# Is there a way to align the text in a column without adding a class to each td (CSS)?

Tags: css, css-tables, text-alignment

I've been trying to figure this out on my own without success. Full disclosure: I'm a beginner.

My goal is to left-align the text in the rightmost column of a table in CSS (while everything else, including all headings, is centered.)

Is there a way to do this without having to assign each td a class? Seems a bit too repetitive ...

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code , show us what you did try

Comment: please describe your question so easily understood by other people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) or [`:last-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) selector to achieve that.

```css
table th, 
table td {
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

table td:last-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` works along with `:last-child`.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

td:last-child, th:last-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Added your and Hao Wu's tips to my notes.